# Read a video in opencv (python)

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to read a video file in opencv (python 2.7), and I just copied the example in the opencv tutorial, but nothing happens:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('input.mp4')

while(cap.isOpened()):
   ret, frame = cap.read()

   gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

   cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
     break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The function cap.isOpened always returns FALSE.I have already tried to use absolute path in the argument of VideoCapture, but I still get the same result. What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Try adding “os.system(‘ls in*’)”

Comment: It works for me in Windows 8 with OpenCV 3 and Python 3.6. I have attached the screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/SuKJr  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define video location or move the video where python is installed

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your OpenCV version is not properly installed. You can check your build infos with `print cv2.getBuildInformation()` if there is any weird components.

I would suggest to rebuild it, or install it via [Anaconda](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/opencv) to be sure not to miss any package.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the full path of the video file. 
For example :-

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("D:\\Video Folder\\input.mp4")
```

I believe this would solve this issue.